# Two electrons in $1\text{s}$ orbit

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, fermions, pauli-exclusion-principle

Suppose that we have two electrons in $1\text{s}$ orbit. According to the Pauli principle, they should have different spins, one up and one down. If I want to calculate the total angular momentum, knowing that $m= \frac12-\frac12=0$, so the states $\left| 1 1\right>$ and $\left| 1 -1\right>$ are not possible. But is the state $\left| 1 0\right>$ still possible? Can I still get $1$ for the total angular momentum?

Comment: That is fixed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

$\left|10\right>$ is a symmetric spin state, so no, it is not possible.

Comment: So in the case of 2 electrons in 2 different orbits, does the spin state have to by asymmetric as well?

Comment: @Michael:  The *overall* state has to be antisymmetric.  This can be accomplished either by having a symmetric spatial state and an antisymmetric spin state, or vice versa.  If the two electrons are in the *same* orbital, then their combined spatial state must be symmetric, and the spin state antisymmetric.  But if they're in different orbitals then their spatial state can be either symmetric or antisymmetric, and so the spin state can be either antisymmetric or symmetric (respectively.)

Comment: And in the case of two different orbitals, you can have superpositions of symmetric and antisymmetric states as well, which complicates things further.  [Andrew Steane has written a nice answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/305532/symmetry-of-two-particle-system-of-electrons) that goes into more depth on this point.